# Hacer accionar un button desde otro button en Android(?)

Tags: android, botón

Necesito accionar un `button` por medio de otro `button` en Android(?)

```
    ButtonBorrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pantalla.setText("")
        }
    });

    //Al precionar este boton que accione el de arriba (ButtonBorrar)
    ButtonRepetirBorrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        //?.............................................
    });
```

Comment: No sería mejor meter la acción de onClick en un método y al oprimir el otro botón también mandar a llamar ese método?

Comment: Bienvenido FABER, te saludo y te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcoas el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganar tu primera medalla!. Además puedes revisar [ask] con información que te ayudará a tener buenas preguntas! :D

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar [performClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()) :

```
  ButtonRepetirBorrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ButtonBorrar.performClick();

        }
    });
```

Al realizar esto ejecutaría la acción del click relacionada a `ButtonBorrar`.